# MySQL tc.log file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Very often if mysql/mariadb does not start, because of an error like "couldn't init tc.log" many people suggest to delete this file. I was wondering which information mysql stores inside the file. It's a binary file and I couldn't find any information about that. Would be good to know, because deleting a file without any clue seems dangerous.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently MariaDB is working on an issue to [clarify tc.log documentation](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16442).

`tc.log` is the distributed transaction (XA) log coordinator, which is created by a fresh installation of MariaDB, not in Oracle MySQL.

Server `--log-tc` option documentation: [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld-options/#-log-tc), [Oracle MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-tc).

So I think the file is useless if your application is not using [distributed transactions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xa-transactions/) and you have only one XA enabled storage engine in your instaces, usually InnoDB:

```
select Engine, XA from information_schema.engines where XA='YES'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Engine: InnoDB
    XA: YES
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Currently XA are supported by InnoDB, TokuDB and SPIDER storage engines so if you want a distributed transaction covering these engines in the same instance you need `tc.log`.

Comment: Thank you! Finally a good answer. tc.log has been a mystery for me.